# Scope of variables inside threaded for loops?

Tags: multithreading, julia

In the following example

```
shared_arr = zeros(4000)
Threads.@threads for thread = 1:4
    tmp_arr = rand(1000)
    for i = 1:1000
        shared_arr[(thread - 1)*1000+i] = tmp_arr[i]
    end
end
```

I believe `shared_arr` is shared among all threads. Is `tmp_arr` allocated 4 times so that each thread has it's own `tmp_arr`?

Comment: I think (but would need to check/think more) that answer is yes, and yes. But that `rand` isn't threadsafe (due to shared global seed) and may behave weirdly. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [scoping rules](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/variables-and-scoping/#man-scope-table) described in the documentation, a new scope is introduced whenever a for-loop is invoked. Since `tmp_arr` isn't declared prior to the loop, it will be a distinct value in each iteration of the for loop. Note that `rand` might not be threadsafe however per @Lyndon White's comment.